# VSCode Scrolling to next line on long lines of code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I highlight a long line of code - if I barely move my mouse to the row above or below it will automatically go to the beginning of the line. Really annoying for simple highlight and change edits. At the moment, I only use my arrow keys as an alternative.. or I have to be very careful and not get close to the row above and below the line I'm working on. I've attached a GIF as an example.

I've looked in the settings for "scroll" options and i'm unable to find anything. Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

https://giphy.com/gifs/3ohc1be4q9OaSsRIPu

Comment: Open an issue for it https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40663

Comment: Did you find any solution? This is getting me crazy, I don't like the word wrap, and I am using a table and it is easy to move the cursor in upper or down line.
Atom works ok, it moves the cursor but does not scroll the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Workaround. Use word wrap: `"editor.wordWrap": "on"`

You can even enable it temporarily (`editor.action.toggleWordWrap` <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>)

[image]